# Atom Editor - How to select rectangle with multi cursor

Tags: atom-editor

I have liked a feature very much in Notepad++, pressing `Alt` and selecting with the mouse enabled a rectangular selection, just like the selection on desktop...can not think of a proper term for it, maybe `rectangular selection` or `vertical selection` or `block selection`. The cool thing was that it worked also with blank line endings, it generated spaces automatically.

Is there a similar functionality in Atom?

So for example, an use case would be to extract a list of files with `tree` command :

```
.
├── element_portals_commands
│   ├── depends.txt
│   └── init.lua
├── element_portals_functional
│   ├── portal_data_api.lua
├── liquid_portals
│   ├── constants.lua
│   ├── crafts.lua
│   ├── depends.txt
│   ├── sounds
│   │   └── fireball_whoosh.ogg
│   └── textures
│       ├── ray_y_tile.png
│       └── README.md
.......
```

place the multi cursor at a fixed width (the last `|` for each line represents the cursor)

```
.                                       |
├── element_portals_commands            |
│   ├── depends.txt                     |
│   └── init.lua                        |
................
│   ├── sounds                          |
│   │   └── fireball_whoosh.ogg         |
│   └── textures                        |
│       ├── ray_y_tile.png              |
│       └── README.md                   |
.......
```

and start typing

```
.                                       <- |
├── element_portals_commands            <- |
│   ├── depends.txt                     <- |
│   └── init.lua                        <- |
................
│   ├── sounds                          <- |
│   │   └── fireball_whoosh.ogg         <- |
│   └── textures                        <- |
│       ├── ray_y_tile.png              <- |
│       └── README.md                   <- |
.......
```

What I do now to achive this:

1. Find and replace the end of line `\r` or `\n` with a lot of spaces `&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;\n`
2. Then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Click</kbd> my way out.
3. Insert a char.
4. Trim the end of the line.

I'm sure there is a better way. It is possible without any plugin? Do you know an alternative?

#### Update :

Some further research showed that

> Add selection below <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd>

places another cursor beneath the current cursor... but it doesn't pad the lines with white spaces. Exists something that also pads the lines ?

Comment: not sure what you mean.  Can you not ctrl-down, then shift-right to select a block?

Comment: I tried to improve the question body, maybe is more clear now.

Comment: `ctrl+down` moves the current selected line (the first one with the cursor) down, whit the default shortcuts.

Comment: `ctrl + mouse left click` I only know this shortcut, and it does almost that but not quite. You can click on multiple lines to select a "rectangle" but not really

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, according to the [official site of Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/features/column-mode-editing.html), this function is called column mode editing.

There is a plugin to do similar thing in Atom, but sadly it will just skip lines if that line is not long enough, instaed of filling space. This is the plugin:

[Sublime-style-column-select](https://atom.io/packages/Sublime-Style-Column-Selection)

Comment: You could also try the multi-cursor-plus plugin.  Not sure if it does what you need.

Answer (score 3):

Today I found a package in Atom named "[column-select](https://github.com/ehuss/atom-column-select)". So far it works perfectly fine. They way it works is very close to the implementation of Block selection of Rstudio and Kate.

It does not add space to fill the gap. It literally let you select vertically if there is anything there (skips empty lines and lines that does not have enough length).

The following gif from their github shows how it works:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you want to select a rectangular region in atom all you have to do is first set the horizontal dimension by selecting some text, then set the vertical dimension by holding CTL-SHIFT and then pressing the up or down arrow. Alternatively you can do this the other way around and set the vertical dimension first with CTL-SHIFT, then let go of CTL but keep holding SHIFT and then use the right or left arrow to select the horizontal dimension.

[image: selecting horizontal dimension]

[image: selecting vertical dimension]

Comment: hello, do you know if one can go down page by page instead of line by line ?

Comment: When I hit the page up/page down buttons nothing happens so I guess not?